# Authentication and Permissions errors in O365 consent flow

Tags: ms-office, office365

I'm using the typical OAuth 2 flow and sending people out to authenticate with the pattern showed in the O365 samples:

`https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&resource={1}&redirect_uri={2}&state={3}`

Frequently, when a user follows the link to the site, it asks them to log in, but without asking them to grant permission to the app it redirects them back to our site with:

`error: access_denied`

`error_description: "AADSTS50020: Calling principal cannot consent due to lack of permissions.\r\nTrace ID: fb1d1e6a-d339-4cba-9c99-b53b50e921a5\r\nCorrelation ID: ac7ef3f1-e8eb-4b0a-b413-e186faf2892c\r\nTimestamp: 2014-07-11 22:11:27Z"`

Why is it doing this, and what can I do to fix it?

A google search for "Calling principal cannot consent due to lack of permissions" came up with nothing.

Comment: I see a similar error if the Office 365 tenant's administrator disabled the ability for users to give consent for apps to access their data, but the description is a bit different ("AADSTS50020: Does not have access to consent.") I'll see if I can dig this up. Out of curiosity, what resource are you trying to access (SharePoint, Exchange?), and what scopes (Mail.Read, etc) do you require?

Comment: In case anyone is curious, steps to detect whether the app allows user-consent or admin-only-consent, there's a helpful article here:

[Managing User Consent for Applications Using Office 365](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/06/05/managing-user-consent-for-applications-using-office-365-apis.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the user in question does not have rights to give consent to the permission that your client_id(app/website) requires.

**Example**

Website/app with Client Id xxxx requires the following permission

*Sharepoint : "Have full control of all site collections".*

If a non site collection administrator logs in then the "AADSTS50020: Calling principal cannot consent due to lack of permissions" error will be returned. The reason being that the user cannot give consent to something that they themselves do not have access to.

This is just an example but should be true for any permission to any resource.

Comment: I'm getting the error even when I specify 'Read and write items in all site collections' with a user who has **Edit** permissions in my sharepoint tenant. So in this case, they do have sufficient read/write permissions, according to the site permissions definitions in sharepoint, but the '...all site collections' part concerns me a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before and I solved it by going to your Azure AD and checking to see if the app in question has the appropriate consents. You can find a guide on how to do this [here](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet). 
I hope that helps.

Comment: Links tend to change or go missing, could you explain some of the contents or quote it here?